# WPF MainWindow won't open when run by outside source, such as a separate program or windows 10 startup folder. Why is this happening?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I'm trying to make a program that will, on startup, open a WPF window and open a browser window. It is able to open the browser window and will still open the WPF visual-studio window thing when run by clicking on it, but when placed in startup it will only open the browser and will not open the other window.

When just placing the file in startup didn't work, I tried making a different program in startup to the original file, which would be somewhere else, but that has the same problem, even when not used on startup. I also tried adding a line to make the window show in addition to the InitializeComponent() step Visual Studio already added for me, but that didn't do anything. I couldn't find anything online that answered my question. Segments of code below:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

         public MainWindow()
{
            InitializeComponent(); //Supposedly will open the window but doesn't
            Window window = Application.Current.MainWindow; //Create an object reference to MainWindow
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://www.website.extension"); //Open Browser Window
            System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer("song.wav");
            player.PlayLooping(); //Play song
            window.Show(); //Force MainWindow to show (doesn't actually work)
}
```

The program is supposed to open on startup, but instead it only opens the website. When run in visual studio, it returns no error message and functions as normal. The problems only start when it is run by an outside source, such as startup or a different program.

Thanks for any help,

Nat

(I'm also pretty new to programming so try to explain what you mean if you use any big programming terms.)

Comment: If you create a new WPF project in Visual Studio, the MainWindow constructor contains no more code than `InitializeComponent();`. Still, the MainWindow is shown on startup of the application. There is no need to call Show() explicitly, especiall not `window.Show()` with `window = Application.Current.MainWindow`, which is usually identical to the current MainWindow instance that you are currently creating.

Comment: Presumably you're creating an instance of `MainWindow` i.e. `new MainWindow()`, can't you just call `.Show()` on that instance?

Comment: @CraigBeaumont You don't need to call Show() at all.

Comment: It functions exactly the same even if I don't call show(), that step was a failed attempt to fix it.

Comment: @Clemens you definitely shouldn't be calling show inside the constructor, without that you will have to call .Show() on that object you've just created

Comment: @NatConfedidential What if you remove all code but InitializeComponent from the constructor? Does your MainWindow show then?

Comment: @Clemens I know there is no call to `Show()` in the generated code, that's exactly what I said. It's shown by the framework i.e. the thing that instantiates the object. The framework gets the `StartupUri` from `app.xaml`, creates an instance of that and then sets `Visibility` to `Visibility.Visible` (equivalent to `.Show()`)